# How can I determine the Node.js version supported by a specific npm library?

Tags: node.js, angular

I am looking for which node version is supported by npm libraries. I am migrating the Angular Project which supports node version 16. I have upgraded to 20, but it's failing. So I have updated all other packages like Angular/cli.

```
"dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^17.1.2",
    "@angular/cdk": "^17.1.2",
    "@angular/common": "^17.1.2",
    "@angular/compiler": "^17.1.2",
    "@angular/core": "^17.1.2",
    "@angular/forms": "^17.1.2",
    "@angular/material": "^17.1.2",
    "@angular/material-moment-adapter": "^17.1.2",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^17.1.2",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^17.1.2",
    "@angular/router": "^17.1.2",
    "@ng-select/ng-select": "^12.0.7",
    "apexcharts": "^3.35.0",
    "bootstrap": "^5.1.3",
    "bootstrap-icons": "^1.8.1",
    "font-awesome": "^4.7.0",
    "html2canvas": "^1.4.1",
    "jquery": "^3.6.0",
    "jspdf": "^2.5.1",
    "mat-select-filter": "^2.4.1",
    "moment": "^2.29.3",
    "ng-apexcharts": "^1.7.1",
    "ng-multiselect-dropdown": "^1.0.0",
    "ng2-search-filter": "^0.5.1",
    "ngx-bootstrap": "^12.0.0",
    "ngx-mat-select-search": "^7.0.5",
    "ngx-order-pipe": "^2.2.0",
    "ngx-pagination": "^6.0.3",
    "ngx-spinner": "^16.0.2",
    "popper.js": "^1.16.1",
    "rxjs": "^7.8.1",
    "sweetalert2": "^11.4.4",
    "tslib": "^2.3.0",
    "zone.js": "^0.14.3"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "^17.1.2",
    "@angular/cli": "^17.1.2",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^17.1.2",
    "@types/bootstrap": "^5.1.9",
    "@types/jasmine": "^5.1.4",
    "@types/node": "^20.11.16",
    "jasmine-core": "^5.1.1",
    "karma": "~6.3.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~3.1.0",
    "karma-coverage": "~2.0.3",
    "karma-jasmine": "^5.1.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^2.1.0",
    "typescript": "^5.3.3"
  }
```

These are my package.json upgraded libraries. after updating also failed.

Thank you in advance, please let me know if anybody has any idea about this.